# Display number of sign-ups

Tags: forms, user-registration, signup

[Our website](http://goodfoodforall.co.uk/our-charter) has a page where visitors can sign a charter. We'd like to display a counter for how many people have entered their details. It needs to update dynamically each time a new person signs up. What's the best approach?

Comment: Hello @Bobby - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately we have no idea how your form is implemented, and as such cannot begin to speculate on how to solve your problem. Should it be done with a 3rd-party product, your question could be considered "off-topic" and would be better addressed in the product's official support channels. We also ask that questions display some amount of research and effort on the asker's part. Please review the [ask] page of our [help] for more information regarding what makes a good question for our community.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is saved in a database you could create a total count function.  You will obviously need to work on the query as its impossible to answer without knowing what your database looks like.  If you aren't saving the data, then theres no chance your going to get this to work.

Here is an example function

```
function userTotalSignupCount() {
  global $wpdb;
  $userTotalSignupCount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM yourTable");
  return $userTotalSignupCount;
}
```

Then you can call the function somewhere in a template like

```
$userTotalSignupCount = userTotalSignupCount();
echo $userTotalSignupCount;
```

Hopefully that will help you get going.

And if you just wanted to display total WordPress users.

```
<?php
$result = count_users();
echo 'There are ', $result['total_users'], ' total users';
?>
```